# How to achieve high availability of instance in openstack

Tags: openstack, kvm

I wanted to launch an instance with high availability with out having risk factor i.e, an instance will be launched in multiple regions(zones) that to sync the state like database(master-slave). When some applications got installed, same should reflect in another region/zone also(mostly image format). Can we do that?.

I have checked some links based on this. I got a confusion after reading all the docs.

- Host-aggregate/Cell in openstack
- Nova evacuate command
- Buildbot tool

Exactly what is the difference among. VM replication & syncing is possiblein Openstack?

Comment: I think I am missing the point to your question, What do you want to be highly available? The OpenStack, meaning controller node, network node etc.? or your application that run on instances deployed over openstack?

Comment: Hi Athafoud, I want to launch an instance in one node(region/zone), If it goes down, I want a parallel instance with the same state of the original(which was launched first with the existing applications) should be available on some other region. Like database if master database goes down salve will be up with the same data whatever master has. Is there any way to create/launch an instance by selecting multiple regions even one goes down, another should be up

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, Open Stack does not support VM replication for now.

There is a component called Remus under the Xen project, which could potentially used by manual configuration as Open Stack supports Xen (https://www.xenproject.org/directory/directory/projects/70-remus.html). But it seems to be slow and unstable.

The newest approach is called reversed virtual machine replication (http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2996894&CFID=918229768&CFTOKEN=85577813), this one seems to be very interesting and some critical problems in VM replication is well defined and elegantly solved. However, I did not find the open source project for it.